# How do i get values of the first duplicate object in a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

How do i get the values of a duplicate object in a json, for example:

```
{ TableName: 'Table_0',
  Rows:
   [ [ 277, '2017-08-22T14:00:00Z' ],
     [ 263, '2017-08-22T15:00:00Z' ],
     [ 265, '2017-08-22T16:00:00Z' ],
     [ 266, '2017-08-22T17:00:00Z' ],
     [ 265, '2017-08-22T18:00:00Z' ],
     [ 264, '2017-08-22T19:00:00Z' ] ] }
{ TableName: 'Table_1',
  Rows: [ [ '{"Visualization":"table","Title":"","Accumulate":false,"IsQuerySorted":false,"Kind":"","Annotation":"","By":null}' ] ] }
```

I just want the values of the first **Rows** object, how do i achieve this?

full json can be found [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY&query=requests%0A%7C%20where%20timestamp%20%3E%3D%20ago(24h)%0A%7C%20where%20resultCode%3D%3D%22404%22%0A%7C%20make-series%20count()%20default%3D0%20on%20timestamp%20in%20range(ago(24h)%2C%20now()%2C%201h)%0A%7C%20mvexpand%20count_%20to%20typeof(long)%2C%20timestamp%20to%20typeof(datetime))

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: It's a snippet of a larger Json

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: I don't see any duplicate values in that array!?

Comment: @xander its the json objects rather than the values themselves, i'm trying to get the values of the first Rows object

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I've tried json[1] but it doesn't work, i'm probably missing something

Comment: so you just want that array `[ 277, '2017-08-22T14:00:00Z' ]`? why don't you use `json.Rows[0]` or am I missing something.

Comment: @xander I want all the arrays in the first rows object. If i do json.rows[0] it'll return: `[ 265, '2017-08-22T14:00:00Z' ]
[ '{"Visualization":"table","Title":"","Accumulate":false,"IsQuerySorted":false,"Kind":"","Annotation":"","By":null}' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.find` to get the target object (based on `TableName` value):

```js
const data = { Tables: 
 [{ TableName: 'Table_0',
    Rows:
   [ [ 277, '2017-08-22T14:00:00Z' ],
     [ 263, '2017-08-22T15:00:00Z' ],
     [ 265, '2017-08-22T16:00:00Z' ],
     [ 266, '2017-08-22T17:00:00Z' ],
     [ 265, '2017-08-22T18:00:00Z' ],
     [ 264, '2017-08-22T19:00:00Z' ] ] },
   { TableName: 'Table_1',
    Rows: [ [ '{"Visualization":"table","Title":"","Accumulate":false,"IsQuerySorted":false,"Kind":"","Annotation":"","By":null}' ] ] }]};

console.log(data.Tables.find(row => row.TableName === 'Table_0').Rows)
```

If you don't support ES6:

```
var targetObject = data.Tables.find(function(row) { 
   return row.TableName === 'Table_0'
})
console.log(targetObject.Rows)
```

You could also use simple array access if you know the index:

```
console.log(data.Tables[0].Rows)
```